# When class is detected as it extends Enum, how to call its valueOf() method?

Tags: java, hibernate, class, enums, hibernate-criteria

I have an `Enum` in `Java`:

```java
public enum TypeOfUser {
    EMPLOYEE("EMPLOYEE"),
    EMPLOYER("EMPLOYER");

    private final String type;
    TypeOfUser(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

And I use it in `Hibernate` mapping, so if I want to add filtering I use `Criteria` interface. I build criteria based on `Map`, at this moment I detect whether it inherits from `Enum` (cause every `Enum` implicitly inherits from Java Enum class) and call `valueOf()` method of `TypeOfUser`:

```java
Class fieldClass = element.getValue().getValue();
if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldClass)) {
     criteria.add(
         Restrictions.eq(element.getKey(), 
         TypeOfUser.valueOf(element.getValue().getKey()))
      );
}
```

But it works only because I have only one Enum im my project, and in future there will be more of them, like `Months` or so. Is there a way, when class is detected as `Enum`, to cast it and then call its `valueOf()` method? Something like:

```java
Class fieldClass = element.getValue().getValue();
if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldClass)) {
     criteria.add(
         Restrictions.eq(element.getKey(),
         ((Enum.class)fieldClass).valueOf(element.getValue().getKey()))
      );
 }
```

I want to do it to avoid `if-else` or `switch` instruction, like:

```java
if (fieldClass.equals(TypeOfUser.class)) {
    value = TypeOfUser.valueOf(key);
}
else if (fieldClass.equals(Months.class)) {
    value = Months.valueOf(key);
}
```

Because they can be really tricky to maintain when many `Enum`s will exist in project. Is there a chance to do it in `Java`? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Why all this reflection code?

Comment: @JBNizet Cause I want to write `QueryRestriction` class, where I can place pagination, filtering, sorting etc then call method like `build()` and it returns me a Criteria. I think it should be as generic as possible, cause it should fitler for fields which can be `Long`, `String`,`Enum` etc or even real classes, like `Meeting` which has `Place`. Maybe I am wrong :) But I think it needs generic code. P.S. `Enum.valueOf(fieldClass, key)` is doing the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `Enum.valueOf`

```
Class<E> enumClass = ...
String name = ...
E e = Enum.valueOf(enumClass, name);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Enum.valueOf(fieldClass, key)` should work in my opinion.